# A way to bypass LINQ queryable NullReferenceException?

Tags: linq

I have a query which is supposed to sum up the hours and pay for each individual user from a specific list. To calculate the total pay, I multiply each instance of hour entries by an instance of an instance of a salary.

The problem is, that sometimes, the salary can return as null, which is intentional. In that case, I'd like to return a 0 instead of a null, however I cannot figure out how to do it.

Here is the query:

```
time.GroupBy(x => x.User).Select(z => new
{
   User = string.Format("{0} {1}", z.Key.Users.Name, z.Key.Users.Surname),
   Hours = z.Sum(x => x.Hours),
   TotalPay = z.Sum(x => x.Hours * (double?)salaries.Where(y => y.User.Id == x.User.Id && y.Date <= x.Date).OrderByDescending(y => y.Date).FirstOrDefault().Salary ?? 0)
});
```

To elaborate, the TotalPay part of the query finds the salary (or logically speaking, their hourly pay) with the date closest to the left of the hours date, multiply it with the hours entry and add it to the final sum. If such an entry happens to not exist, then the query should return the 0, which i tried doing with the *?? 0* part, but  my visual studio still ends up throwing an error without actually doing any calculating.

Comment: Are you sure that's a queryable? Isn't that an enumerable?

Comment: "the salary can return as null" - do you mean `salaries` itself? The fact that you're casting what looks like a query to `double?` is very odd. My guess is that this isn't your real code. It would *really* help if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, I mean the `salaries`. The initial reason why i added the `(double?)`, was because the `?? 0` part at the end wouldn't work if the variable wasn't nullable, or so i understood. This is indeed my real code, as shabby as it looks.

Comment: I don't see how `salaries.Where(...)` would ever return a `double?` of any kind. What type is `salaries`? I'd expect `salaries.Where(...)` to return a *sequence* of results, not a *single* result. (If you'd called `salaries.SingleOrDefault(...)` then the code would make a lot more sense. Again, please provide a [mcve] so we don't have to guess how this is all working.

Comment: @JonSkeet Look at the rows below TotalPay. It is just the formatting that is odd.

Comment: I've tried recreating the classes required for this query just to compile. It's super odd. The `User` class looks like this: `public class User { public User Users; public string Id; public string Name; public string Surname; }`. I agree that I don't think this is real code.

Comment: @Magnus: Ah, thanks for that. Yes, it's clearer now. With the initial formatting it was *very* unclear. I still think a [mcve] would be useful though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing a little bit here, but I would try:

```
time.GroupBy(x => x.User).Select(z => new
{
   User = string.Format("{0} {1}", z.Key.Users.Name, z.Key.Users.Surname),
   Hours = z.Sum(x => x.Hours),
   TotalPay = z.Sum(x => x.Hours * 
        salaries
          .Where(y => y.User.Id == x.User.Id && y.Date <= x.Date)
          .OrderByDescending(y => y.Date)
          .Select(y => (double?)y.Salary)
          .FirstOrDefault() ?? 0)
});
```